# Heredoc returns error "did not find expected '-' indicator" despite YAML being correct

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, heredoc

I am trying to use a heredoc to create a resource in Kubernetes as follows:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: max-pods
spec:
  validationFailureAction: audit
  background: false
  rules:
    - name: restrict-pod-count
      match:
        resources:
          kinds:
            - Pod
      context:
        - name: podcounts
          apiCall:
            urlPath: "/api/v1/pods"
            jmesPath: "items[?spec.nodeName=='minikube'] | length(@)"
      preconditions:
        any:
        - key: "{{ request.operation }}"
          operator: Equals
          value: "CREATE"
      validate:
        message: "A maximum of 10 Pods are allowed on the Node `minikube`"
        deny:
          conditions:
            any:
            - key: "{{ podcounts }}"
              operator: GreaterThan
              value: 10
EOF
```

If I write the YAML in a file and run `kubectl apply -f file.yaml`, it works as intended. But when I use it as shown above, it says:

```
error: error parsing STDIN: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 69: did not find expected '-' indicator
```

I am not extremely familiar with heredocs, so there should be something I am missing, but the error does not help me (the file does not have 69 lines...)

Comment: This is works for me. Are you sure this is the entire config? because this has about 30 lines and the error shows line 69.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validate.message contains an expression that would be expanded in the heredocs. You need to escape that like this:

```
[...]
      message: "A maximum of 10 Pods are allowed on the Node \`minikube\`"
[...]
```

You could also use the heredoc delimiter with single quotes to disable the expansion. With that you could use your original version.

```
cat <<'EOF' | kubectl apply -f -
[...]
EOF
```